# calling a function but i cannot understand the logic for the arithmetic

Tags: c

```
#define N 4
#define EXPON(x) x * x * x
#define HALF(x) x * 0.5

int main(){
    int i = N + 6;
    int j = HALF(i);
    int k = EXPON(j + 0);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i, j, k);
}
```

Return of `j` is somehow not equal to sum of `(j+0)` can someone please explain?

Comment: What is this printing? From the logic it should be printing `"10, 5, 125"`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's printing `10, 5, 5`?

Comment: @Kupiakos Oh. That makes sense. He defined his macro poorly.

Comment: The third `printf` gives `5` because `5 + 0 * 5 + 0 * 5 + 0 --> 5`. You better ***always*** use parentheses in the macro.

Comment: I don't see any functions apart from `printf`. **Macros are no functions!**

Answer (score 8):

You're not actually calling a function but using a function-like macro.  Macros perform text substitution, so after expansion this:

```
int k = EXPON(j + 0);
```

Become this:

```
int k = j + 0 * j + 0 * j + 0;
```

Which (due to operator precedence) is the same as this:

```
int k = j + (0 * j) + (0 * j) + 0;
```

Which is not what you want.

When definining a function-like macro you should **always** parenthesize the parameters **and** the resulting expression:

```
#define EXPON(x) ((x) * (x) * (x))
```

So now you'll get what you would expect:

```
int k = ((j + 0) * (j + 0) * (j + 0));
```

Comment: You beat me. Nearly identical answers.

Comment: You should also put parentheses around the result.

Comment: @Barmar Good catch.  Edited.

Comment: Meh. No point in keeping mine around. You said it first, you said it better.